# how to wrap text taken from database without splitting up words?

Tags: asp.net, css, database, html

Okay, this is one that's stumped me a while now..

I have a database of stories. I want to display the content of a chapter, inside of a div. My problem is getting the text to wrap without splitting words, which cuts down on readability. For example, the word 'birthday' is at the edge of my div, and it will get wrapped like this:

birthd 
ay.

How do I fix this? Probably really simple, I'm just over thinking it..

Here is the css..

```
    .dvChapContent
    {
     float: left; 
     display: block; 
     width: 750px; 
     white-space:normal;
     word-break: break-all; 
     word-wrap: normal;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `white-space:normal`

you can also look for similar properties like `word-wrap: normal;` and `text-wrap:normal;`

edit:
not using `word-break` property might work.

Comment: I thought text-wrap wasn't supported in any of the browers? That's what the w3schools site says.. I don't even /know/ anymore. I got the text in the div to wrap but it's still breaking up words just like before. Would it help if I mention that the text has paragraph tags in it?

Comment: If your text is wrapped in paragraph `<p>` tag, than style paragraph tag like this `p { word-break:keep-all; }` and don't listen to much W3Schools, it's good site but they are not updated, you must test yourself what property works and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/hFVSJ/)

```
.dvChapContent {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: keep-all;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

Comment: now the text in the div isn't wrapping at all... :sigh: This has been bugging me for going on a week now..

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope it will work for you this time ;)

Comment: word-break: keep-all didn't seem to do anything for me :/

Comment: Okay, after more digging, I realized why the word break wasn't working. In between all the words is '&nbsp', which only looks like a character space but isn't. But my problem is, I use ckeditor for creating the chapters. How do I make it to where ckeditor doesn't do put '&nbsp' inbetween every character?

Comment: Please open some editor and replace all `&nbsp;` with one blank space :) use function Find and replace, you can use MS Notepad for that purpose.

Comment: I'm supposed to do that for every possible chapter? That doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Comment: Ok, here's a code for you `<script>$(function() { $('.dvChapContent').html($('.dvChapContent').html().replace("&nbsp;", " ")); });</script>` put it just before `</body>` tag. I've updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/hFVSJ/) is that what you need?